# ContentResolver insert does not work android

Tags: android, kotlin, mediastore, android-contentresolver

I want to save a file (Image, Audio, Video, Document) from the internal storage of my application to the Public directories depending on the File type. So i made this function

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    private fun saveFileUsingMediaStore(file: File, mimeType: String, fileName: String, destinationDirectory: String) {
        var uri: Uri? = null
        val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, mimeType)
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, destinationDirectory)
        }
        runCatching {
            with(appContext.contentResolver) {
                insert(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)?.let {
                    uri = it
                    file.inputStream().use { input ->
                        openOutputStream(it)?.use { output ->
                            input.copyTo(output, DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
                        } ?: throw IOException("Failed to open output stream.")
                    }
                } ?: {
                    toast("Failed to create MediaStore record")
                    //throw IOException("Failed to create new MediaStore record.")
                }
            }
        }.getOrElse {
            uri?.let { failedUri ->
                toast("Delete orphan entry")
                appContext.contentResolver.delete(failedUri, null, null)
            }
        }
    }
```

How ever, when the code reach to the `insert` method, the code stops and does not do anything. Its like the insert never happens. Is there something wrong?

Comment: Show with wich parameters you call this function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved when i changed the `MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` with `MediaStore.*.getContentUri("external")`

The * gets its value by the fileType of the file that i want to save.

```
val externalUri = when (fileType) {
            IMAGE_TYPE -> MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri("external")
            AUDIO_TYPE -> MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri("external")
            VIDEO_TYPE -> MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")
            DOCUMENT_TYPE -> MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")
            else -> MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")
        }
```

So now the code that works is the following

```
 with(appContext.contentResolver) {
     insert(externalUri, contentValues)?.let {
       .....
```

However, i dont know the real reason that caused the error